# Force Docker to mount code volume in the host not the guest

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have been using [the official wordpress docker repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) to create a wordpress website.
Now, since the code (wordpress) in this image is inside the container, I would like to extract the code out in the host.

I am using docker compose and I added:

```
  volumes:
    - ./code:/var/www/html
```

in order to force Docker work on an external directory.
I got this error message:

WARNING: Service "wordpress" is using volume "/var/www/html" from the previous container. Host mapping "/dir/code" has no effect. Remove the existing containers (with `docker-compose rm wordpress`) to use the host volume mapping.

Answer (score 4):

Read error message and

`docker-compose rm wordpress`